# Как собрать Map используя RxJava2 и RxAndroid?

Tags: android, rxjava, rxandroid, rxjava2

Есть у меня полный список обьектов который мне нужно отсоритировать по условию, в итоге я получаю список отсортированых обьектов, каждый обьект в этом списке содержит еще список который тоже нужно отсортировать по условию и добавить его в Map только в том, случае если после сортировки его размер `> 0` .

В итоге нужно получить такой `Map<ОбьектИзПервогоОтсортированогоСписка, ОтсортированныйСписокОбьектовКоторыеСодержитПервыйОтсортированыйСписок>`

Вот так если наглядно

`Map<CallServiceCode, ArrayList<CallServicePart>>`

Вот, что у меня есть

```
private Observable<CallServiceCode> getUnansweredQuestionList()
{
    return Observable.fromIterable(getServiceCodeArrayList())//
                     .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation()) //
                     .filter(iServiceCode -> getServiceCodeFormStatus(iServiceCode).isUnanswered());
}
```

Тут я беру `getServiceCodeArrayList()` это первичный список который еще никак не отсортирован и сортирую его получая в итоге `Observable<CallServiceCode>`

Потом я делаю вот, что

```
private Map<CallServiceCode, ArrayList<CallServicePart>> getSortedMap()
{
    Map<CallServiceCode, ArrayList<CallServicePart>> result = new HashMap<>();

    getUnansweredQuestionList().filter(callServiceCode -> ???);

    return result;
}
```

Вот тут мну нужно зайти в каждый обьект `callServiceCode` , взять его список `ArrayList<CallServicePart>` отсортировать его по условию и если размер больше 0 то добавить его в Map

не могу понять как это сделать с помощью Rx2

Кто работает с этой технологией подскажите куда смотреть

Если есть вопросы пишите

**Правка**

Спасибо @ЮрийСПБ за подсказку вот, что получилось

```
private Map<CallServiceCode, ArrayList<CallServicePart>> getSortedMap()
{
    Map<CallServiceCode, ArrayList<CallServicePart>> result = new HashMap<>();

    getUnansweredQuestionList() //
                                .filter(callServiceCode -> Observable.fromIterable(callServiceCode.getCallServicePartList()) //
                                                                     .filter(servicePart -> servicePart.getServicePartFormStatus().isUnanswered())//
                                                                     .count() //
                                                                     .toObservable() //
                                                                     .blockingFirst(0L) > 0) //
                                .subscribe(callServiceCode -> result.put(callServiceCode, callServiceCode.getCallServicePartList()));

    return result;
}
```

Но все таки осталось несколько вопросов которые не могу понять, мне кажется, что то не так сделал в этом примере

Во первых `.blockingFirst(0L) > 0)` этот метод если я правильно понял, блокирует первый заимиченый item , а это значит , что не важно сколько таких будет в списке `callServiceCode.getCallServicePartList()` он возьемет первый посчитает его кол-во и если оно `>0` , то этот обьект по условию фильтра будет добавлен.

Мне нужно проверить все элементы списка по условию, найти те которые соответсвуют условию и если их количество будет больше 0 , то взять `callServiceCode` как ключ , и список елементов которые мы только что проверили взять как значение и сложить их в `Map`

Что то вроде такого должно получиться

```
private Map<CallServiceCode, ArrayList<CallServicePart>> getSortedMap()
{
    Map<CallServiceCode, ArrayList<CallServicePart>> result = new HashMap<>();

    getUnansweredQuestionList() //
                                .filter(callServiceCode -> Observable.fromIterable(callServiceCode.getCallServicePartList()) //
                                                                     .filter(servicePart -> servicePart.getServicePartFormStatus().isUnanswered())//
                                                                     .isNotEmpty()) //
                                .subscribe(callServiceCode -> result.put(callServiceCode, Observable.fromIterable(callServiceCode.getCallServicePartList()) //
                                                                                                    .filter(servicePart -> servicePart.getServicePartFormStatus().isUnanswered()));

    return result;
}
```

Comment: `.filter(callServiceCode -> Observable.fromIterable(callServiceCode.getServiceParts()).filter(servicePart -> servicePart.isValid()).count().toBlocking().first() > 0);`?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб круто, что можно использовать еще раз `fromIterable()` внутри условия, но все равно не совсем то, что нужно было... я добавил в вопрос, можете глянуть?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо @DVarga в итоге сделал так

```
return getUnansweredQuestionList()
    .collect(HashMap<CallServiceCode, List<CallServicePart>>::new,(hashMap, callServiceCode) -> {
        List<CallServicePart> callServiceParts = Observable.fromIterable(callServiceCode.getServicePartList())
                    .filter(s -> !s.getServicePartFormStatus().isUnanswered())
                    .toList().blockingGet();
        if (!callServiceParts.isEmpty())
            hashMap.put(callServiceCode, callServiceParts);
    }).blockingGet();
```

Ну или чтоб красивее то так

```
return getUnansweredQuestionList()
       .collect(HashMap<CallServiceCode, List<CallServicePart>>::new, (hashMap, callServiceCode) -> {
           List<CallServicePart> filteredParts = getFilteredServiceParts(callServiceCode.getServicePartList());
           if (!filteredParts .isEmpty())
               hashMap.put(callServiceCode, filteredParts);
        }).blockingGet();
```